# Error in installing SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

when I try to install Microsoft SQL server management studio I get this error message:
"the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:0x80070020"
How to overcome?

Comment: restart your system and try again ,if you are not able to see what the process is

Comment: tried before but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error (SSMS v17.7) on Win7 x64.   After downloading a few times (and I'm blushing as I type this), I realised that I was running low on disk space.  Cleaned up, ran again, worked :-)

Worth checking?

Comment: Somebody must have forgot the free space check on the installer :) I fell into this trap too.

Answer (score 0):

I would sometimes receive this error when using an installer we keep in our company drive, especially if there was a possibility of connection issues when transferring the installer to the target machine.

When a reboot doesn't work, using the newest installer from Microsoft works for me.  If I get the issue with the newest installer, I download another copy to be sure that there wasn't an issue with the download.  For whatever reason, the installer file seems to be sensitive to transfer issues.

Currently, the link to the official download is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms